# I am unable to push my complete project in one got on git via pycharm

Tags: python-3.x

I have my project in Pycharm but I want to push the complete project on git in one go. Is there any way to do it

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't a tutorial resource; you have to give an attempt, and then ask a question if you are stuck. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks!

Comment: I have added the git repo through VCS and able to push a single file on git but rather than pushing files one by one. I would like to push all at once

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand the exact problem. But you need to be a little more detailed so that we can understand the problem. In general, under the VCS you need to map the git repo where you want to push your code. Then you will get the option to push or pull under **git** suboption.

Try https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/commit-and-push-changes.html

Comment: I have added the git repo through VCS and able to push a single file on git but rather than pushing files one by one. I would like to push all at once

Comment: Firstly, git does not treat files separately. Each commit created as a blob object and pushed to the remote. I am not sure where did you check that it pushes the file separately. If you are not too familiar with Pycharm. First, try to use a simple git push followed by git commit.